Scraping Only First Page Using Proxy Server: Subsequent Pages Fail to Load
I'm working on a web scraping project using Python and Playwright to collect data from a website. When accessing the website without a proxy server, my IP gets blocked. To prevent this, I use a proxy server (ScraperAPI) and rotate user agents. While the first page scrapes successfully, subsequent pages fail to load.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
import asyncio
import sqlite3
import random
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

SCRAPER_API_KEY = 'your_scraper_api_key'
SCRAPER_API_URL = 'https://api.scraperapi.com/'

def build_scraperapi_url(url):
    params = {
        'api_key': SCRAPER_API_KEY,
        'url': url,
        'country_code': 'us',
        'device_type': 'desktop',
        'session_number': '123',
        'keep_headers': 'true'
    }
    return f"{SCRAPER_API_URL}?{urlencode(params)}"

def load_user_agents(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            user_agents = [line.strip() for line in file if line.strip()]
        if not user_agents:
            raise ValueError("User agents list is empty.")
        return user_agents
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to load user agents: {e}")
        return []

headers_template = {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br, zstd",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Origin": "https://www.example.com"
}

async def scrape_product_urls(category_url, user_agents):
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.new_page()

        headers = headers_template.copy()
        headers["User-Agent"] = random.choice(user_agents)
        await page.set_extra_http_headers(headers)

        scraperapi_url = build_scraperapi_url(category_url)
        await page.goto(scraperapi_url, timeout=90000)
        
        product_urls = []
        product_divs = await page.query_selector_all('div.ProductList0__productItemContainer')
        if not product_divs:
            print("No products found")
            return product_urls

        for div in product_divs:
            link = await div.query_selector('a')
            if link:
                href = await link.get_attribute('href')
                full_url = f"https://www.example.com{href}"
                product_urls.append(full_url)

        await browser.close()
        return product_urls

async def main():
    user_agents = load_user_agents('user_agents.txt')
    if not user_agents:
        print("No user agents available. Exiting.")
        return

    category_urls = [
        'https://www.example.com/shop/clothing?page=1',
        'https://www.example.com/shop/clothing?page=2',
        'https://www.example.com/shop/clothing?page=3'
    ]

    for category_url in category_urls:
        try:
            product_urls = await scrape_product_urls(category_url, user_agents)
            print(f"Scraped {len(product_urls)} product URLs from {category_url}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error while scraping {category_url}: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

